# 'crawling' tag synonyms

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

There are currently separate tags for [crawling](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crawling) and [web-crawlers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-crawlers) and [site-crawler](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-crawler).

[image]

Since they are essentially the same thing, should these tags be merged into one? Should synonyms be made?

Comment: I performed the synonym merge.  "crawling" and "site-crawler" are now synonyms of "web-crawlers".

Answer (score 2):

They seem similar enough to be merged to me.

It looks like [web-crawlers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-crawlers) already has [crawler](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crawler), [crawlers](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crawlers), and [web-crawler](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-crawler) as synonyms.  It would probably make the best canonical tag for [crawling](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crawling) and [site-crawler](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-crawler) as well.

Comment: I would keep Googlebot separate but agree that the pothers should be merged. Thoughts?

Comment: googlebot and crawl-errors (from the screenshot) are certainly separate, but the proposal that  crawling, web-crawlers and site-crawler should be merged is fine.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't referring to those two, just the three Stephen had merged.